# Unix commands through Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, unix, privileges, rights

I have created a PL/SQL a Java Source, and privileges have been granted.

The PL/SQL procedure is executing and no error is coming up.
Within the JavaSource there is the following unix command:

ls -al > /orion/list/list.txt

the file List.txt is not being created within the directory.

How would i know the problem if no errors are coming up?
Could this be a problem of rights being given to oracle from unix.

Oracle is on unix sun solaris

Comment: have you seen this ask Tom thread ? http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3069633370832

Comment: There may be a trace file on the Oracle server that will have more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Stephen ODonnell.

I have implemented the exact same Java functionality (creating a file containing a directory listing) recently.

I needed to grant the following:

```
-- this grants read privilege on STDIN
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission(
   grantee => '<username>', 
   permission_type => 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission', 
   permission_name => 'readFileDescriptor', 
   permission_action => null
);

-- this grants write permission on STDOUT
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission(
   grantee => '<username>', 
   permission_type => 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission', 
   permission_name => 'writeFileDescriptor', 
   permission_action => null
);

-- this grants execute privilege for the 'ls' command
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission(
   grantee => '<username>', 
   permission_type => 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
   permission_name => '/bin/ls', 
   permission_action => 'execute'
);

-- this grants read, write, delete and execute on all 
-- of the referenced directories (subdirectories of <directory>)
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission(
   grantee => '<username>', 
   permission_type => 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
   permission_name => '<directory>/-', 
   permission_action => 'read,write,delete,execute'
);

-- this grants execute on sh
EXEC dbms_java.grant_permission(
   grantee => '<username>', 
   permission_type => 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
   permission_name => '/bin/sh', 
   permission_action => 'read,execute' 
);
```

Hope this helps.
Ollie.

Comment: Yes, that code looks familiar - probably best to run it instead or relying on the ROLE I suggested, just incase the role doesn't give everything needed.

Comment: I have set the following permissions and still the problem persists. Could this be due to the Oracle user not being the same as the Unix user 

begin DBMS_JAVA.grant_permission ('ORION', 'java.io.FilePermission','TestHostCommand', 'read ,write, execute, delete'); end; begin DBMS_JAVA.grant_permission ('ORION', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission','writeFileDescriptor', ''); end; begin DBMS_JAVA.grant_permission ('ORION', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission','readFileDescriptor', ''); end;

Comment: "Could this be due to the Oracle user not being the same as the Unix user". No, the user in the database is seperate from the database that accesses the OS commands. Does Oracle have access permissions on the OS directories?

Comment: so in this case that would be ORION 
cause i'm still new at this. 

Thanks for your patience

Comment: It would be Oracle that accesses the OS directory on behalf of the ORION user. In the case I have used, the Unix directories that Oracle had to access were all owned by the OS Oracle user so there were no OS directory permission issues. I also ensure that the files within the directory are either owned by the OS Oracle user or at least the Oracle user has permissions to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks how can i check for the Oracle User through UNIX if they have the right privileges and what priveleges do i have to look for? Or need to be given to Oracle

Comment: I'd ask your Unix sysadmin (or at least your DBA) to check for you. I'm no unix expert so I can't direct you to look in the unix groups and how the security model works etc. but one of the two roles I mentioned should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks i'll ask the DBA to check for permissions.

Answer (score 3):

From a distant memory, I am fairly certain you need to grant some privileges to the user executing the Java before it is allowed to execute unix commands.

Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chten.htm

I think you need to give it java.io.FilePermission permission. One way to do this is to grant the role JAVASYSPRIV to your user.  I have nowhere to test this out at the moment, but if that is not correct the link above should point you in the correct direction.

Comment: The permission has been granted by a DBA
The problem is that there are no errors being recorded on my Sql Navigator but the file list.txt is not being created within the directory

Comment: Ask your DBA to look in the alert logs to see if Oracle is reporting any issues.